# Data Encryption Keys and Key Encryption Keys

Tags: google-cloud-platform, encryption, google-cloud-kms

I hope someone can help me to understand how DEK and KEK works in layman term.

This is my understanding so far

**Part 1**
Uploaded data is stored in chunks. Each chunk is encrypted with DEK. DEK is stored near the chunked data.
**Part 2** DEK of the data chunk is wrapped with KEK
**Part 3** KEK is stored in KMS.

This sentence from a Google's course material really tripped me.

> The wrapped data encryption keys are then stored with this data

**My brain goes crazy with these questions:**

1. What is this *wrapped data encryption keys*? Isn't that the KEK in part 2?
2. If that's the KEK in part 2, shouldn't that be in KMS?
3. If yes, does KMS store data?
4. If no, how many DEKs a chunk of data has? 2 DEKs?
5. What keys do we(users/customers)keep?
6. We store the data with which keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is this wrapped data encryption keys? Isn't that the KEK in part 2?

The wrapped DEK is the result of encrypting the DEK with the KEK. The key encryption key is called that because it encrypts (data encryption) keys.

> If that's the KEK in part 2, shouldn't that be in KMS?

> Does KMS store data?

No. As the name suggests, a key management system only stores keys, and specifically KEKs.

> How many DEKs does a chunk of data have? 2 DEKs?

One. Data is encrypted only once, so there is only one key.

> What keys do we (users/customers) keep?

Only the KEK. When using a KMS, not even that key is known to you, the user of the KMS.

> We store the data with which keys?

With the wrapped DEK.

---

Here is a concrete example:

Data (i.e. plaintext): `yellow submarine`
KEK (aka. master key): `my-secret-master`
DEK (randomly generated for each piece of data): `ttlly-random-dek`

Ciphertext: Base64(AES(Data, DEK)) = `TJ4SLFTy0sMdvGe55QCuYQ==`
Wrapped DEK: Base64(AES(DEK, KEK)) = `lOEmql1JuSONZ8uLorc/vQ==`

The second operation is done by the KMS, if there is one (it has to be, because it's the only one in possession of the KEK, and it will never disclose it).

What you store together: `TJ4SLFTy0sMdvGe55QCuYQ==` and `lOEmql1JuSONZ8uLorc/vQ==`.

And to reconstruct the plaintext given `TJ4SLFTy0sMdvGe55QCuYQ==` + `lOEmql1JuSONZ8uLorc/vQ==`:

DEK: AES'(Base64'(`lOEmql1JuSONZ8uLorc/vQ==`), KEK) // = `ttlly-random-dek` Plaintext: AES'(Base64'(`TJ4SLFTy0sMdvGe55QCuYQ==`), DEK)

The first operation is done by the KMS if there is one (again, it has to be, because the KEK is involved).

In the example above I conveniently chose 16 bytes of data and 16-byte keys, so I could gloss over block cipher modes and IVs/nonces. In practical applications the IVs for each encryption have to be retained as well, of course.

Note that the KMS never sees your data, and it only has to encrypt and decrypt tiny amounts. That is why we do all of this; only you, the owner of the data ever sees it in plaintext (assuming the KMS is an honest party, obviously).

Comment: For the question **What keys do we (users/customers) keep?**. The answer is none. Google does not make the KEK or DEK accessible. Google-managed encryption is transparent to users. For the question **We store the data with which keys?**. The client does not store data with keys. The keys are added to the stored data by Google.

Comment: @JohnHanley, since the docs referenced in the question say "The wrapped data encryption keys are then stored with this data", the question is about client-side encryption, not Google-managed encryption.

Comment: DEK and KEK are Google-managed encryption details. That has nothing to do with client-side encryption. Google does not wrap client encryption keys with data.